# how to schedule a procedure in oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle10g

i have to schedule a stored procedure in oracle 10g?

assume

```
create table t1(name varchar2(10));
insert into t1 values('hi');

create or replace procedure insertname
as
begin
insert into t1 values('hi');
end;
```

now my requirement is everday at 11 am my procedure has to be executed automatically.

how can i implement it.

actually i studied about dbms_scheduler.create_job. but i am not able to implement it can any body explain me how can i schedule my stored procedure.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm

or with way better examples:
http://www.apex-at-work.com/2009/06/dbmsscheduler-examples.html

The interesting part for you (simply change the job_action)

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job (  
 job_name            => 'TEST_JOB',  
 job_type            => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',  
 job_action          => 'begin /* some process code */ commit; end;',  
 number_of_arguments => 0,  
 start_date          => sysdate +1/24/59, -- sysdate + 1 minute  
 job_class           => 'ADMIN',  -- Priority Group  
 enabled             => TRUE,  
 auto_drop           => TRUE,  
 comments            => 'Testrun');
```

Comment: Najzero , what is the code i have to write in job_action in place of some process code

Comment: you could place the actual code of your procedure in there (if its really that small) or simply add the call of your procedure like `BEGIN schema.procedurename; commit; END;`

Comment: @Najzero you'd want to add the repeat, otherwise that job will only run one. ie ` repeat_interval     => 'freq=daily;byhour=11;byminute=0;bysecond=0',`